# how to use for loop inside itemBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am trying to use for loop inside itemBuilder to show inline ads, i have two ListView.separated one is list from data api and the second one from admob ads , my code is work fine and show the ads but it just show once because i used this line of code i want to convert it to for loop but i don't know how I just want to change this line of code

`if (index == 10) { return _getAdWidget();}`

i want to convert it to for loop and execute every 10 index please help

here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text("طرائف عن الحيوانات"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List snap = snapshot.data;

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("error"),
              );
            }
            return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snap.length,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = snap[index];
                final dataJoke = data["joke"];
                final dataAnswer = data["answer"];

                return Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("images/110.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        " ${snap[index]['joke']}",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        " ${snap[index]['answer']}",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      trailing: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: Size(1, 30),
                            primary: Colors.grey[900], // background
                            onPrimary: Colors.yellow,
                            elevation: 0),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          const urlPreview =
                              "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNUBhb_cM6E";
                          await Share.share(
                              "$dataJoke \n $dataAnswer \n للمزيد من الطرائف\n$urlPreview");
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.share_outlined),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == 10) {
                  return _getAdWidget();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just simple, try to change this line of code

```
if (index == 10) {
                  return _getAdWidget();
                }
```

to

```
if (index % 10 == 5) {
                  return _getAdWidget();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snap.length + (snap.length ~/ 10),
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     if (index % 10 == 0) {
        return _getAdWidget();
     }
     final data = snap[index];
     final dataJoke = data["joke"];
     final dataAnswer = data["answer"];

     return Card(
        elevation: 6,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                 image: AssetImage("images/110.png"),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ),
         ),
         child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        " ${snap[index]['joke']}",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        " ${snap[index]['answer']}",
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      trailing: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: Size(1, 30),
                            primary: Colors.grey[900], // background
                            onPrimary: Colors.yellow,
                            elevation: 0),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          const urlPreview =
                              "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNUBhb_cM6E";
                          await Share.share(
                              "$dataJoke \n $dataAnswer \n للمزيد من الطرائف\n$urlPreview");
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.share_outlined),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

Comment: got error at return ListView.separated the error is the named parameter 'separatorBuilder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. try to adding  the required argument

Comment: how do i fix it ?

Comment: i should use this line of code  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {}

Comment: but i dont know what to return inside curly brackets

Comment: Hey @onlineapps, I’ve used a ListView.builder instead.

Comment: Please check my edit.